# python convert 123.456 to 0.123456

Tags: python, math

i want convert the float to [0.something] but my data have very different numbers like

123.456,
12.3456,
1234.56

i know i can do

```
ConvertNum = 123.456
convertNum /= 1000
print(convertNum)
```

but my problem is if when i don't know how many 10 multiplication i need to  make it 0.something

so i tried something like this

```
ConvertNum = 123.456
convertStr = str(ConvertNum).split(".")
convertStr = f"0.{convertStr[0] + convertStr[1]}"
print(float(convertStr))
```

but my question is, is this the best way to do that?

is there any function like in math library that can do it automatically?

Comment: FWIW, you could replace the period with empty string instead of splitting and concatenating…

Comment: 1) Use a loop:  `while n >= 1.0: n = n / 10`.  2) AFAIK no.  This is a really obscure (and mostly useless) operation.

Comment: I find the premise questionable. Why transform numbers into completely different arbitrary numbers?

Comment: (That's what I meant by useless.  But you put it better!   The operation discards information, and makes no sense from a mathematical perspective.  Now ... if the OP was also counting the number of divisions ... that would be useful.)

Comment: these data is for Y coordinates in a PDF

Comment: This explanation hardly clarifies anything. Isn’t magnitude important for Y coordinates in PDFs too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use maths... The number of whole digits in a number can be found using `log`:

```
from math import ceil, log10

def normalize(a):
    return a / 10 ** ceil(log10(a))
```

Test cases:

```
>>> print(normalize(1.23))
0.123

>>> print(normalize(123.45))
0.12345

>>> print(normalize(0.1))
0.1
```

Comment: thanks that was exactly what i was searching for

Comment: I agree with everything in this answer, except I would have put an exclamation mark instead of an ellipsis after "Use maths"! Maths are awesome!